# Error with 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: http, cors, http-post, httprequest

I have a webpage I made with angular 2 that is a form and at the end of it  the form must be sent to my java server. But I'm unable to send, I get the error `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.`

I have already changed my server so it will send the `Access-Control-Allow` headers. The function is like this:

```
public static Response buildResponse(int status, Object reponseObject, MediaType mediaType) {
    Response.ResponseBuilder rb = Response.status(status).entity(reponseObject);
    if (mediaType != null) {
        rb = rb.type(mediaType);
    }
    rb = rb.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    rb = rb.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    rb = rb.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, accept");
    rb = rb.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    System.out.println("teste");
    return rb.build();
}
```

I have also tried to add the header `'Access-Control-Request-Method': 'POST'` to the page request, but I still get the error. The problem is not with the software functionality itself because it works fine if I install and activate the CORS plugin for chrome, but I can't request the user to install the plugin to use my site. Does anyone knows what I'm missing? I have been sarching for sometime and the only solutions I found was to disable this browser security (I can't ask the user to do that) and to add the headers on the request, what I already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve my problem. The problem was in the communication between my page and my server. The CORS block is imposed by the browser and the server needs to send a header authorizing the access (the headers I put in the function in the question).  What I was missing was the header in the `OPTION` method. My JavaScript code automatically send and `OPTIONS` request (the `preflight request`) before the actual `GET` or `POST` method. What I did was to manually implement the `OPTIONS` method in the server that respond with the necessary headers.